# Why RStudio source pdf output difference with R prompt?

Tags: debian, r, rstudio

I get correct output of the following code for `Rscript code.r` but damaged file when running RStudio source in the minimal project, which I do not understand. 
Code

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(iris)
```

There are quite big differences in Details of those two sessions listed following for RStudio vs R prompt. 
So some setting of RStudio must be wrongly configured.

1. locale: 9 vs 11 things
2. namespace: 1 vs 5 things

### Details in RStudio session in a minimal project

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.12.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

### Details in R

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.12.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0    bit_1.1-12        colorspace_1.3-2  DBI_0.7          
[5] bit64_0.9-7       data.table_1.10.4
```

OS: Debian 8.7
R: 3.4.0
RStudio: 1.0.143
RStudio support: [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115006965667-Why-this-phase-difference-in-RStudio-pdf-output-in-Debian-8-7-) but you need to be logged in to read the thread and works in Firefox (my Google Chrome is not accepted there to get logged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works in RStudio where RStudio requires `dev.off()` for some reason

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(iris)
dev.off()
```